# implement url request in android and getting result

Tags: java, android

In map android application i want to exexcute url request and in the result i want to take the *lat* and *long* and put marker on the map

> http://travelplanner.mobiliteit.lu/hafas/query.exe/dot?performLocating=2&tpl=stop2csv&stationProxy=yes
>   &look_maxdist=150&look_x=6112550&look_y=49610700

**The result is on browser**

> 6,113204;49,610280;200403005;Belair,
>   Sacré-Coeur;http://travelplanner.mobiliteit.lu/hafas/stboard.exe/dn?L=vs_stb&input=200403005&start
>   id=A=1@O=Belair,
>   Sacré-Coeur@X=6,113204@Y=49,610280@U=82@L=200403005@B=1@p=1481807866;

Comment: is the result always in json format ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here, if you want to search a location with a name and get location with lat lng you can use this method using **Google Maps Geocoding API**,.

Read [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro)

```
private class  GeoCodeBySearch extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String[]> {
            ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            String searchedLocation;


            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(addressEditTextViewInTop.getWindowToken(), 0);

                String locationSearchByUser = addressEditTextViewInTop.getText().toString();

                // searchedLocation = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=srilanka&sensor=false";
                searchedLocation = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="+locationSearchByUser+"&sensor=false";

                super.onPreExecute();
                dialog.setMessage("Please wait");
                dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                dialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            protected String[] doInBackground(String... params) {
                String response;
                try {
                    response = getLatLongByURL(searchedLocation);
                    Log.d("response",""+response);
                    return new String[]{response};
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return new String[]{"error"};
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String... result) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result[0]);

                    double lng = ((JSONArray)jsonObject.get("results")).getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").getDouble("lng");

                    double lat = ((JSONArray)jsonObject.get("results")).getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").getDouble("lat");

                    Log.d("latitude", "" + lat);
                    Log.d("longitude", "" + lng);


                    if (pickCoordinates != (null)) {
                        pickCoordinates = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                        CameraUpdate center = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(pickCoordinates);
                        googleMap.moveCamera(center);
                        CameraUpdate zoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15);
                        googleMap.animateCamera(zoom);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed. Try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                    dialog.dismiss();

                }
            }
        }
```

And this is what you get when you call it , i have only taken lat lon and zoomed it ,but can get any data bellow mentioned

```
    {
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "1600",
               "short_name" : "1600",
               "types" : [ "street_number" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Amphitheatre Pkwy",
               "short_name" : "Amphitheatre Pkwy",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Mountain View",
               "short_name" : "Mountain View",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Santa Clara County",
               "short_name" : "Santa Clara County",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "California",
               "short_name" : "CA",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "United States",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "94043",
               "short_name" : "94043",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA 94043, USA",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 37.4224764,
               "lng" : -122.0842499
            },
            "location_type" : "ROOFTOP",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 37.4238253802915,
                  "lng" : -122.0829009197085
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 37.4211274197085,
                  "lng" : -122.0855988802915
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJ2eUgeAK6j4ARbn5u_wAGqWA",
         "types" : [ "street_address" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can use Android volley plugin for performing Network requests**

In android studio, open your build.gradle(Module:app) file under Gradle Scripts , add the following line in dependencies and sync the Gradle

```
*compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'*
```

**In your java page:-**

```
String url = your_url_here;


// Request a string response, 
// you will get response from url as string


           StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                   new Response.Listener<String>() {
                       @Override
                       public void onResponse(String response) {


                           // you will get the response as string here
                           //String response holds the response from url

                          Log.d("response from url",response);

                          //you can do whatever you want with the retuned string response






                       }
                   }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
               @Override
               public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                   //this part will work if there is any error

                   System.out.println("Something went wrong!");
                   error.printStackTrace();

               }

           })
           {
               @Override
               protected Map<String, String> getParams()
               {
                   Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();


                   //you can pass parameters ,if you want to

                   //in this case its not needed


                   //params.put("parameter1", value1);
                  // params.put("parameter2",value2);



                   return params;
               }
           };


           // Add the request to the queue

           Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(stringRequest);
```